# How to split string and numbers separated by : in text file into rows and columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to machine learning and python and I am finding a problem with the below line of data in a text file

```
2019-12-16-12-40-53, Intensity: 0, BMP280_Temp: 25.66, BMP280_Pressure: 904.09,SI7021_temp: 24.82, SI7021_hum: 41.548294, Ds18B20 Temp : 16.81.
```

I want to keep the string name as column title and the value after the ':' in respective columns. I was able to separate them as rows, but each row has the string name too. How do I separate them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df[col].str.split(':',expand=True)` ?

Comment: Is the data in a csv file?

Comment: No. It's a .txt file.

Comment: Is it a single row? or multiple rows with same structure/column names?

Comment: The data which is displayed is in a single row. LIke that we have multiple rows with Strings like 'Intensity, BMP280_Temp'  which are constant over all rows, and these strings I want to bring put it as column names.